# Is Billy the Puppet's laugh an animal sample or an artificial sound effect?

Tags: sound-effects, saw

In the [Saw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_(franchise)) movies, a laughing noise was played whenever [Billy the Puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_the_Puppet_(Saw)) appeared.  You can hear the laughing noise repeated several times in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAoKHrgq3gk). Is that noise an artificially created sound effect, or did they record an animal making that noise?

Comment: To me its look like a basic toy sound. Talking toy always sound little weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very late, sorry. I too am interested in finding the source because I recall my grandmother owning a bat Halloween prop that would hang over the door way and when you hit it it would shake and make a similar sound source. Anyways I found this video which is kind of like what my grandmother had except it wasn't a pumpkin and was covered with felt. -

Comment: According to the Youtube description for that video, the pumpkin toy was made in 1994 by Spearhead Ind Inc.  The sound is pretty much the same as Billy's laugh, so I think they must have recorded it and tweaked it a bit.  Good find.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say it's a created sound effect. I've fairly exhaustively searched online and I can find nothing about who created it. I'm of the mind that that's because it was too commonplace to credit. It's a simple thing to create and many similar laugh sounds can be found (for free) across the Internet.

So I'm saying - *artificially created sound effect*. I don't think a *definitive* answer will *ever* be given for this question, unless one of the production team happened to comment.